# printing a mysql query

Tags: mysql, syntax

I prepared a statement:

```
set @table_name = 'W13LAT';

set @sql_text = concat('drop table if exists ',@table_name);
set @sql_text2 = concat('create table ', @table_name, '
(`Student_ID_NUMBER` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
');

prepare stmt from @sql_text;
prepare stmt2 from @sql_text2;  

execute stmt;
execute stmt2;
```

The problem is that it doesn't create the table. I'd like to debug by printing out the mysql query generated from the prepared statements. Is this possible right from the mysql command line? For example, I'd like to remove the `execute stmt;` and `execute stmt2;` and replace them with `echo stmt;` or `print stmt;` or whatever the command is to see the actual statement generated. Also, if you see an error i made as to why it didn't create the table, please let me know!
Thanks!

Comment: how about `select @sql_text`

Comment: For me, your script works.

Answer (score 0):

You're right...it does work. There's this tiny little button at the bottom of Sequel Pro that says 'refresh table list' :/

And thanks for the `select @sql_text` statement. It worked as well.